# Knockoutjs vm not binding to correct element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have two viewmodels

```
1. vm1 (for page1.php)
2. vm2 (for page2.php)
```

and they are in separate js files. vm1 is bound like this:
**VM1.js**

```
$(function() {
    //other stuff
    // see orders is defined here
    gs.vm1 = function(){
            var orders = ko.observableArray([]);
        }();
    ko.applyBindings(gs.vm1, document.getElementById('page1_id'));
);
```

vm2 is bound to a dialog like this:
**VM2.JS**

```
$(function(){
    //other stuff
    // orders is NOT defined here
    gs.vm2 = function(){...}();
    ko.applyBindings(gs.vm2, document.getElementById('page2_id'));
});
```

as you can see I am being explicit in my bindings to specific elements as mentioned on the kojs site: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

When I load the page1.php where vm1 is supposed to be bounded I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return orders }"
Message: orders is not defined
```

This is the template code in page1.php where I am using the foreach:

```
<div id="page1_id">
    <div data-bind="foreach: orders">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
        <span data-bind="text: ...some observable..."></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see orders is defined as an `observableArray` in vm1 but for some reason ko is looking it up in vm2. I debugged through
the ko code and it seems context is set to vm2.

my head tag looks like this (just to show how I am including these script files):

```
<script src="scripts/vm1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/vm2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am using a module revealing pattern which exposes vars I want to expose and orders is one of them.

Comment: @Ray, why should it be this? in my vm this would be the window context.

Comment: Could you try to remove last two brackets `()` from the definition of the `vm1` viewmodel?

Comment: @YuriyN., what would that do?

Comment: That will convert your Immediately Invoked Function Expression into simple function, which is suitable for being Knockout's viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and will post the answer in case anyone makes the same mistake as I did.
As I said in my question vm1 is for a dialog and the id given to that dialog is page1_id. I didn't have that dialog on page2 and when ko was applying bindings it couldn't find that id and would pass null to

```
ko.applyBindings = function (viewModelOrBindingContext, rootNode) {...}
```

as second arg.
if you look at ko code then this is how the node is set:

```
rootNode = rootNode || window.document.body;
```

so if you pass null then the body is basically your context and since orders is not defined there hence the error.

so I guess the lesson is (at least for me) to make sure if you are being explicit in your bindings that they are properly defined on the desired page.